# What is the best way to initialise a NumPy masked array with an existing mask?

Tags: numpy, masked-array

I was expecting to just say something like

```
ma.zeros(my_shape, mask=my_mask, hard_mask=True)
```

(where the mask is the correct shape) but `ma.zeros` (or `ma.ones` or `ma.empty`) rather surprisingly doesn't recognise the `mask` argument. The simplest I've come up with is

```
ma.array(np.zeros(my_shape), mask=my_mask, hard_mask=True)
```

which seems to involve unnecessary copying of lots of zeros.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a masked array:

```
In [162]: x = np.arange(5); mask=np.array([1,0,0,1,0],bool)    
In [163]: M = np.ma.MaskedArray(x,mask)

In [164]: M
Out[164]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, 2, --, 4],
             mask=[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)
```

Modify `x`, and see the result in `M`:

```
In [165]: x[-1] = 10

In [166]: M
Out[166]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, 2, --, 10],
             mask=[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)

In [167]: M.data
Out[167]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 10])

In [169]: M.data.base
Out[169]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 10])
```

The `M.data` is a `view` of the array used in creating it.  No unnecessary copies.

I haven't used functions like `np.ma.zeros`, but

```
In [177]: np.ma.zeros
Out[177]: <numpy.ma.core._convert2ma at 0x1d84a052af0>
```

`_convert2ma` is a Python class, that takes a `funcname` and returns new callable. It does not add mask-specific parameters.  Study that yourself if necessary.

`np.ma.MaskedArray`, the function that actually subclasses `ndarray` takes a `copy` parameter

```
copy : bool, optional
        Whether to copy the input data (True), or to use a reference instead.
        Default is False.
```

and the first line of its `__new__` is

```
    _data = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
                     order=order, subok=True, ndmin=ndmin)
```

I haven't quite sorted out whether `M._data` is just a reference to the source `data`, or a `view`.  In either case, it isn't a copy, unless you say so.

I haven't worked a lot with masked arrays, but my impression is that, while they can be convenient, they shouldn't be used where you are concerned about performance.  There's a lot of extra work required to maintain both the `mask` and the `data`.    The extra time involved in copying the `data` array, if any, will be minor.

Comment: The bottom line then is that no copy is made, so my simple version is fine as is.  Thanks for reassuring me.